# Create a correctly aligned footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I created a footer that I would like to reproduce on my site, after many tests here is the best result obtained:

The image of the footer I would like to make : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRNEj.png

How can I match the image on my site please? I have tried so many things that I don't even understand what I'm doing so if you have any explanations and help I'd be delighted...

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, html {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, .87);
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 100%;
}

.topbar {
    height: 80px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(img/background.svg);  
    background-color: rgba(62,62,62, 1);
}

.topbar nav {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.topbar nav a {
    color: #9F9F9F;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 21px;
}

.topbar nav a:hover, .topbar nav a.active {
    color: #94C8D0;
}


.header-logo {
  padding: 0px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 25vh;
}

.login {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.login_btn {
  margin: auto 25px auto;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #3b3b3b;
}

.circuit {
  background-image: url(img/background.svg);    
  background-color: rgba(62,62,62, 1);
  padding: 192px 0 112px;
}

.dark {
background-color: rgb(35,35,35);
padding: 192px 0 192px;
box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

.header_title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 1000;
  font-size: 72px;
  word-spacing: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 72px;
}

.header_second_title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #9F9F9F;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 16px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: 500;
}


.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.invite_btn {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  background-color: #1A9BB6;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  
}

.support_btn {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #282828;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 32px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #9F9F9F;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #9F9F9F;
}

  #footer {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: grid;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr .6fr .6fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "logo product resources business" 
    "social . . design";
}
  
  li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 8%;
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 1px;
}
  
  .flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
}
  
  #footer li a {
    color: rgb(22,145,176);
    text-decoration: none;
}
  
  .logo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-area: logo;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-top: .5rem;
}
  
  .img {
    padding-top: .5rem;
    width: 25vh;
    cursor: pointer;
}
  
  .logo h4 {
    line-height: 1rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}
  
  .copyright {
    padding-top: .3rem;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: rgb(97,97,97);
}
  
  .product {
    grid-area: product;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: .5rem;
}
  
  .resources {
    grid-area: resources;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: .5rem;
}
  
  .business {
    grid-area: business;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.social { 
    grid-area: social;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.design {
    grid-area: design;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Poseidon | The Perfect Discord Bot</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="img/favicon.svg">

</head>

<body>

    <header class="topbar">
        <a href="#"><img class="header-logo" src="img/logo.svg" alt="Poseidon Logo" href="index.html"></a>
        <nav>
            <div class="middle">
                <a href="invite.html">Invite</a>
                <a href="commands.html">Commands</a>
                <a href="documentation.html">Documentation</a>
                <a href="premium.html">Premium</a>
                <a href="support.html">Support</a>
                
                <div class="login">
                    <a href="" class="login_btn">Login<i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="circuit">
        <h1 class="header_title">The Perfect <br>Discord Music Bot.</h1>
        <h2 class="header_second_title">Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2> 
        <div class='container'>
            <a href="#" class="invite_btn">Invite</a>
            <a href="#" class="support_btn">Support</a>
            </div>
    </div>


    <div class="dark">
        <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
        <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>

        <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
        <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>

        <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
        <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="circuit">
        <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
        <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="logo">
            <div class="flex">
                <img class="img" src="img/logo.svg" alt="Poseidon Logo" href="index.html">
            </div>


            <div class="copyright">&#169; Poseidon Bot 2012 - All Rights Reserved.</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="product">
            <li><b>Product</b></li>
            <li><a href="#">Invite</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Commands</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Premium</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="resources">
            <li><b>Resources</b></li>
            <li><a href="#">Docs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Provacy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Refunds</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="business">
            <li><b>Business</b></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="design">
            designed with <span style="color: red;">&#10084;</span> by <span style="color: #00e09d;">My Discord
                ID</span></div> <!-- Javascript clickable text // add js function -->
        <div class="social">
            <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/ffffff/github.png" href="https://google.fr" /></a>
            <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/ffffff/discord-logo.png" href="#" /></a>
            <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/android/24/ffffff/twitter.png" href="#" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It looks close enough. Can you be more specific ? If want it to be exactly like the image, just add margins and paddings to match the spacing.

Comment: Basically the positioning is not the same, the text is not centered/there is a bad symmetry and yes I tried with the padding and the margin but unfortunately as I said I did not succeed at all... that's why also the result of the image and so different on the rendering of my site is that there are different concerns may be that I can not identify them all I remain a beginner x)

Answer (score 1):

I just add a new class as .links and fix your Products Resources and Business you can check it, and change a little bit about right bottom edge text, give footer relative and text to absoulte right:0 bottom : 0 and make text smaller. Hope helps.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, html {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, .87);
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 100%;
}



.circuit {
  background-image: url(img/background.svg);    
  background-color: rgba(62,62,62, 1);
  padding: 192px 0 112px;
}

.dark {
background-color: rgb(35,35,35);
padding: 192px 0 192px;
box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}


h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #9F9F9F;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #9F9F9F;
}

  #footer {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding-top:3em;
    position:relative;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
  
  li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 8%;
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 1px;
}
  
  .flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
}
  .links{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-between;
    height:50%;
  }
  #footer li a {
    color: rgb(22,145,176);

    text-decoration: none;
}
  
  .logo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-area: logo;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-top: .5rem;
    padding-bottom:2rem;
    width:40%;
}
  
  .img {
    padding-top: .5rem;
    width: 25vh;
    cursor: pointer;
}
  .right-side{
    width:60%;
    display:flex;
  }
  .right-side div{
    margin-right:2em;
  }
   .right-side div b{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-bottom:1em;
  }
  .logo h4 {
    line-height: 1rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}
  
  .copyright {
    padding-top: .3rem;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    color: rgb(97,97,97);
}
  
  .product {
    grid-area: product;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: .5rem;
}
  
  .resources {
    grid-area: resources;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: .5rem;
}
  
  .business {
    grid-area: business;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.social { 
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.design {
    grid-area: design;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Poseidon | The Perfect Discord Bot</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="img/favicon.svg">

</head>

<body>



    <div id="footer">
        <div class="logo">
            <div class="flex">
                <img class="img" src="img/logo.svg" alt="Poseidon Logo" href="index.html">
            </div>


            <div class="copyright">&#169; Poseidon Bot 2012 - All Rights Reserved.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
          <div>
            <b>Product</b>
            <ul class="links">

                <li><a href="#">Invite</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Commands</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Premium</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <b>Resources</b>
            <ul class="links">

                <li><a href="#">Docs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Provacy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Refunds</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <b>Business</b>
            <ul class="links">

                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="design">
            designed with <span style="color: red;">&#10084;</span> by <span style="color: #00e09d;">My Discord ID</span></div> <!-- Javascript clickable text // add js function -->
        <div class="social">
            <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/ffffff/github.png" href="https://google.fr" /></a>
            <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/ffffff/discord-logo.png" href="#" /></a>
            <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/android/24/ffffff/twitter.png" href="#" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's even worse I think :(  https://i.imgur.com/5Bi4itP.png

Comment: Actually : 
HTML : https://bin.readthedocs.fr/erbonf.txt 
CSS : https://bin.readthedocs.fr/rankey.txt

Comment: :( try this one.I can't get what you want actually.

Comment: Which one did I not understand?

Answer (score 1):

How about trying this one? I have kept the codes relevant to the footer part only.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, .87);
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 100%;
}

#footer {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr 1.3fr;
  grid-template-areas: "logo product resources business" "social . . design";
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#footer ul {
  margin-top: .5rem;
}

#footer ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 5%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}

#footer ul li a {
  color: rgb(22, 145, 176);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: .7rem;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  grid-area: logo;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-top: .5rem;
}

.img {
  padding-top: .5rem;
  width: 25vh;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.logo h4 {
  line-height: 1rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.copyright {
  padding-top: .3rem;
  font-size: .65em;
  color: rgb(97, 97, 97);
}

.product {
  grid-area: product;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.resources {
  grid-area: resources;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.business {
  grid-area: business;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.social {
  grid-area: social;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.design {
  grid-area: design;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: right;
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Poseidon | The Perfect Discord Bot</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="img/favicon.svg">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="logo">
      <div class="flex">
        <img class="img" src="img/logo.svg" alt="Poseidon Logo" href="index.html">
      </div>
      <div class="copyright">&#169; Poseidon Bot 2012 - All Rights Reserved.</div>
    </div>
    <ul class="product">
      <li><b>Product</b></li>
      <li><a href="#">Invite</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Commands</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Premium</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="resources">
      <li><b>Resources</b></li>
      <li><a href="#">Docs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Provacy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Refunds</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="business">
      <li><b>Business</b></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="design">
      designed with <span style="color: red;">&#10084;</span> by <span style="color: #00e09d;">My Discord
                ID</span></div>
    <!-- Javascript clickable text // add js function -->
    <div class="social">
      <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/ffffff/github.png" href="https://google.fr" /></a>
      <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/ffffff/discord-logo.png" href="#" /></a>
      <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/android/24/ffffff/twitter.png" href="#" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Still not suitable for what I have on my screen, it's even worse than before thanks anyway :/